# How to get ActiveRecord to use :cast_booleans?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql2

When using Ruby on Rails with the mysql2 adapter, I have several BIT columns that I want to access and write to in my database. However, when `ActiveRecord` tries to write to the BIT column, mysql complains that `x'30'` and `x'31'` (ie, '0' and '1') are too large for a BIT(1) column.

The adapter, mysql2, has a hash option in the connection's query function,  `connection.query(str, :cast_booleans=>true)`, to be able to cast `FalseClass` and `TrueClass` to `b'0'` and `b'1'` rather than `x'30'` and `x'31'`. However, I never access `.query` directly, I leave that up to `ActiveRecord` (otherwise, what's the point of rails?).

How do I tell `ActiveRecord` to use the `:cast_booleans`?

Comment: AFAIK, specifying your field to be of `:boolean` type takes care of casting 1 and 0 to true or false respectively. How does your model define these BIT fields?

Comment: `ActiveRecord::Base` takes care of looking up the field and defining the accessor methods right before I use it. The model is the default produced by a scaffold that looks like `rails generate scaffold my_table name:string active:boolean` (except I delete the migration file since the table already exists in the database). Which is essentially empty. The above produces `class MyTable < ActiveRecord::Base end`

Answer (score 0):

I dig into rails sourcecode, and found:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb

maybe you can override `quoted_true` and `quoted_false`?